# give parameter from Controller to another Controller in JavaFX not working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Yes, i saw this answer [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml). But it's not working.

`setDayParting` works from Controller Nº1 but when i'm call `updatePreview` in Controller Nº2 the parameter what i passed is not there.
Why this don't work?

- **Passing parameters in Controller Nº1:**

  ```
  private void giveParameterToController() {
      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(Main.newFileScreenFile));
      NewFileScreenController newFileScreenController;
      try {
          Pane pane = fxmlLoader.load();
          newFileScreenController = fxmlLoader.getController();
          newFileScreenController.setDayParting("Working");
          myController.setScreen(Main.newFileScreen);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```
- **Controller Nº2:**

> ```
> public void setDayParting(String parting){
>     dayParting = parting;
>     System.out.println(dayParting);
> }
>
> private void updatePreview(){
>     System.out.println(dayParting);
> }
> ```

```
output:
Working
null
```

Comment: When is `updatePreview()` called? Do you ignore the value stored in your `pane` variable on purpose?

Comment: @fabian If i don't do the pane thing i cant have access to the controller, the updatePreview is called when I'm in the screen of controller 2.

Comment: But in this case simply invoking `fxmlLoader.load()` without the assignment would also work. Furthermore, if you do not show this `Pane` either from the loading method or from the controller's `initialize` method, you probably use different scenes with different controller instances for displaying and for setting the data.

Comment: @fabian remove it but i still getting different instances of the controller...

Comment: You need to pass the data to the controller that is created when you load the `Pane` that is actually shown on screen...

Comment: @fabian solved it, thanks you for the information.